# How to Query all fields of grand parent record with SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, master-detail

I have a `App__c` with n number of fields.
`Page__c` is another custom object has few fields and a field `App_Id__c` which is **Master-Detail to App__c object**.
`Field__c` is another custom object has fields and a field `Page__Id__c` which is **Master-Detail to Page__c object**.

I am querying all the `Field__c` object records, but the issue I am facing is When I query a record of `Field__c` I also need the query to get all fields of the corresponding Grand parent record `App__c`.

I know we can get the grand parent record's field like for eg:**Name** like shown in below query, but I dont want to mention each and every field in the query like this, I want to get all the field values of the grand parent record without having to write each and every field in the query.

```
List<Field__c> fieldRecords = [Select Id, Name, Page_Id__r.App_Id__r.Name From Field__c];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around it, you will need to write out `Page_Id__r.App_Id__r.<field>` for every field you want from your grandparent record.

The best you'd be able to do is potentially save some typing by breaking out the query for granpdarent records into a separate query. You'll need to be the one to decide if it's worth it to expend an extra query and deal with needing to pull the grandparent record from a map every time you need to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SOQL and a little bit of [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) magic should work for you.

This is simple anon apex and I advise you to break it out into its own method that could accept many `queryObject` and many type of `relationshipAPI`.

```
String relationshipAPI = 'Parent__r.GrandParent__r.';
String queryObject = 'Child__c';

String[] fieldNames = new String[] {};
DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = GrandParent__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = describeResult.fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()) {
    fieldNames.add(relationshipAPI + fieldName);
}

String soql = ''
    + 'select'
    + ' Id'
    + ', ' + String.join(fieldNames, ', ')
    + ' from ' + queryObject;

Database.query(soql);
```

The idea here is that using the `relationshipAPI` to traverse from child through to grandparent, a describe operation obtains the tokens needed to access the API names of the grandparent fields. This is then built into a `String` using the `join()` method from [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) and later used in a dynamic SOQL.

Note, you will need to consider some `null` checking and field that are not "queryable" such as those when Person Accounts are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at [FIELDS(ALL)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm) but it unfortunately doesn't look like you can use it for traversing relationship fields like this.

Your other option appears to be doing something like [this](https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/dynamic-soql-query-fetch-fields-object-salesforce/) to build a SOQL string, but formatting it so that the fields are coming off the parent/grandparent records.

EDIT: See TSmith's answer for some example code; they were kind enough to go in-depth.